# Проблемы с update

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

```
<?php require "bd.php";
$id = $_GET['id'];

$t = $_POST['tit'];
$tt = $_POST['mane'];

if(isset($_POST['s1'])){


  R::exec("UPDATE `stat` SET `it` = '$t' WHERE `stat`.`id` = '$id'");   
    echo "<a href='admin.php'>Назад</a>";
}
//UPDATE `stat` SET `title` = 'Проверка' WHERE `stat`.`id` = 1;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="upd.php">
<input type="text" name="tit" placeholder="Введите заголовок"><br><br>
<textarea name="mane"> Введите контент </textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="s1" value="Готово">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Проблема здесь `R::exec("UPDATE`stat`SET`it`= '$t' WHERE`stat`.`id`= '$id'");` Кто может сказать, почему переменную $id не видят.(когда подставляю обычные числа всё работает).

Comment: Сначала получите текст запроса в переменную, со всеми подстановками, потом выполняйте. В промежутке - выведите значение переменной. И сами посмотрите, и нам покажите.

Comment: мож потому, что вы пришли на страницу с $_POST ?

Comment: $id = $_GET['id']; я взял с ссылки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполняя submit формы генерируется `POST` запрос по url прописанному в атрибуте формы action. В вашем случае `upd.php`. В глобальный массив `_GET` попадают переменные query string из url.

Необходимо пробрасывать в форму значение id либо в input type=hidden (предпочтительно) и забирать из `_POST`, либо в url формы  `action="upd.php?id=1"` - попадет в `_GET`.